# A script to check out all the source codes required to compile some specific packages like rosdep?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any tool to check out all the source codes required to compile some specific packages like rosdep?

rosdep install the packages via apt, however I'd like to compile them from source codes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187493/a-script-to-check-out-all-the-source-codes-required-to-compile-some-specific-packages-like-rosdep?/) by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 317 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using rosinstall (http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall) you can checkout a list of packages from different version control servers/systems (git, svn, hg etc...)....

And to select packages to install use the [rosintall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1